# Why $f_1$ commutes with the product up to boundaries

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, tensor-products, differential-graded-algebras

Let $(A,m_1)$ be a differential graded algebra, $m_2:A\otimes A\to A$ its product and $H^*A$ its homology, on which there is another product induced by $m_2$ which I'll call equally. I'm trying to follow the steps in page 9 of [these notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910179.pdf), right before section 3.5 and I'm stuck right at the begining.

Let us choose a morphism of chain complexes $f_1:H^*A\to A$ inducing the identity.  Since it is a morphism of chain complexes, each component should be a morphism of dg algebras, but since after this there is a failure of $f_1$ to commute with the product, I guess the author only means that it has to commute with the differentials. I think the most obvious way to choose it is just choosing representatives, which is clearly commutes with the differentials. The text says that there exists a degree $-1$ map $f_2:H^*A^{\otimes 2}\to A$ such that

$$f_1 m_2 = m_2 (f_1 ⊗ f_1) + m_1 f_2.$$

I don't see why this is true. Let's take the map which chooses representatives. Then

$$f_1m_2([a],[b])=f_1([a][b])=f_1([ab])=ab+m_1(c_1) \text{ for some } c_1\in A.$$

On the other hand

$$m_2(f_1\otimes f_1)(a,b)=(a+m_1(c_2))(b+m_1(c_3))=ab+am_1(c_3)+m_1(c_2)b+m_1(c_2)m_1(c_3).$$

Therefore, the difference between these operations is

$$m_1(c_1)-am_1(c_3)+m_1(c_2)b+m_1(c_2)m_1(c_3).$$

> How can this expression take the form of $m_1f_2$ for a map $f_2:H^*A^{\otimes 2}\to A$ of degree $-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that a morphism of chain complexes is just required to commute with the differentials in any case (and I don't see what it would mean that each component would be a morphism of dg algebras, since components are just vector spaces).

In this case, as you said $f_1: H^*(A)\to A$ is just required to (be linear and) pick for each $x\in H^n(A)$ a representative $f_1(x)\in A^n$. Then you want to show that there is $f_2: H^*(A)\otimes H^*(A)\to A$ such that 
$$ f_1(xy) = f_1(x)f_1(y) + m_1(f_2(x\otimes y)). $$

You showed that, by definition of the product on $H^*(A)$, there is some $c\in A$ such that $f_1(xy)=f_1(x)f_1(y)+m_1(c)$. Now you just have to see that $c$ can be chosen linearly as $c=f_2(x\otimes y)$.

But you can for instance choose a basis $(e_i)$ of $H^*(A)$ and define $f_2(e_i\otimes e_j)$ to be any valid $c$, and extend $f_2$ by linearity to the whole space. You can check that this gives a correct answer to the problem.

Comment: I added that dg algebra morphism part afterwards, I don't know what I was thinking of at that moment. Thank you.

What do you mean by "any valid $c$"? What would make some $c$ not to be valid?

Comment: I mean any $c$ satisfying the previous equation, so in this case $f_1(e_ie_j)=f_1(e_i)f_1(e_j)+m_1(c)$.

Comment: Is it obvious that such $c$ exists? I mean, $f_1$ is already chosen, basically I need a solution to $m_1(c)=f_1(e_ie_j)-f_1(e_1)f_1(e_j)$.

Comment: This is basically what you proved in your second in-line equation. But really it is just the definition of the product in $H^*(A)$. If $x=[a]$ and $y=[b]$, then $xy=[ab]$, for any choice of representatives $a$ and $b$ (which is well-defined because $A$ is a dg-algebra), which exactly means that if $d$ is any representative of $xy$ then $d=ab+m_1(c)$ for some $c$.

Comment: Hi, do you know if there is a way to solve this without choosing a basis? I'm interested in the case where the ground ring is not necessarily a field, so $H^*(A)$ might not be free.